# Ignore events generated from method invocations

Tags: slack-api

I have the following case:

1) A user sends a direct message to my bot (which has been installed with the Slack app).

2) The message generates an event which is sent to a webhook on my server. The message gets processed, and a response is sent to the user (via the chat.postMessage api (https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)).

3) Now, another event is generated (with type "message", and subtype "bot_message") and sent to my webhook.

Is it possible when sending a message (with the `chat.postMessage` method) to make Slack not generate a corresponding event? (Since I'm the one sending the message, it is completely unnecessary for me to receive an event telling me that I have indeed sent a message.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think it is possible. You can not subscribe to specific message sub_types.

I had the same issue when using the message events and I just told my bot to ignore all messages that have a sub_type.